# Tapping Notification wont open the react native application

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I have a problem with opening my react-native app from notification panel. When a push notification sent from webserver (backend) is received, tapping on the notification from the notification tray wont open the app. Also the onNotificationOpened method is not getting Called.
At the same time When notification was pushed from firebase console it opens the app on tap. Also the onNotificationOpened is getting called. Is there some thing to code for getting the app opened from notification Tap..??

I have tried adding onNotificationOpened listener in App.js which works only for notifications sent from firebase console.

Notification json received from console

```
    { _body: 'Good After noon',
   _data: {},
   _notificationId: '0:15474xxxxxxxxxx',
   _sound: undefined,
   _subtitle: undefined,
   _title: 'Good After noon',
   _android:
    { _notification: [Circular],
      _actions: [],
      _autoCancel: undefined,
      _badgeIconType: undefined,
      _bigPicture: undefined,
      _bigText: undefined,
      _category: undefined,
      _channelId: undefined,
      _clickAction: undefined,
      _color: undefined,
      _colorized: undefined,
      _contentInfo: undefined,
      _defaults: undefined,
      _group: 'campaign_collapse_key_1764xxxxxx',
      _groupAlertBehaviour: undefined,
      _groupSummary: undefined,
      _largeIcon: undefined,
      _lights: undefined,
      _localOnly: undefined,
      _number: undefined,
      _ongoing: undefined,
      _onlyAlertOnce: undefined,
      _people: [],
      _priority: undefined,
      _progress: undefined,
      _remoteInputHistory: undefined,
      _shortcutId: undefined,
      _showWhen: undefined,
      _smallIcon: { icon: 'ic_launcher' },
      _sortKey: undefined,
      _tag: 'campaign_collapse_key_1764xxxxx',
      _ticker: undefined,
      _timeoutAfter: undefined,
      _usesChronometer: undefined,
      _vibrate: undefined,
      _visibility: undefined,
      _when: undefined },
   _ios: { _notification: [Circular], _attachments: [] } }
```

Notification json sent from server

```
{ _body: 'A new booking has been scheduled on 14-01-2019 5:00PM to 6:00PM',
   _data: { a_data: '{"type":"Booking","subtype":"create","id":{"id":"5c3cxxxx"}}' },
   _notificationId: '0:15474xxxx',
   _sound: 'default',
   _subtitle: undefined,
   _title: 'Booking',
   _android:
    { _notification: [Circular],
      _actions: [],
      _autoCancel: undefined,
      _badgeIconType: undefined,
      _bigPicture: undefined,
      _bigText: undefined,
      _category: undefined,
      _channelId: undefined,
      _clickAction: 'android.intent.action.MAIN',
      _color: undefined,
      _colorized: undefined,
      _contentInfo: undefined,
      _defaults: undefined,
      _group: undefined,
      _groupAlertBehaviour: undefined,
      _groupSummary: undefined,
      _largeIcon: undefined,
      _lights: undefined,
      _localOnly: undefined,
      _number: undefined,
      _ongoing: undefined,
      _onlyAlertOnce: undefined,
      _people: [],
      _priority: undefined,
      _progress: undefined,
      _remoteInputHistory: undefined,
      _shortcutId: undefined,
      _showWhen: undefined,
      _smallIcon: { icon: 'ic_launcher' },
      _sortKey: undefined,
      _tag: undefined,
      _ticker: undefined,
      _timeoutAfter: undefined,
      _usesChronometer: undefined,
      _vibrate: undefined,
      _visibility: undefined,
      _when: undefined },
   _ios: { _notification: [Circular], _attachments: [] } }
```

Comment: Can you share Firebase notification json file which server send it you. there is some specific rules about that like "click_action"

Comment: i have already compared both the json files from server and console. But couldnt findout any differences. I tried adding click_action too.

Comment: do you have intent-filter in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Cant add here it says too long.

Comment: <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>

Comment: this one I m mentioning

Comment: yeah.  there is   `<service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
  </service>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186913/discussion-between-aflah-ali-and-nazir-dogan).